# AJAX responsetext to global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("Get","/topjob/php/data.json");
    req.onload = function (){
        var ourData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        randerHTML(ourData);
        randerHTML2(ourData);
    req.send();
};
```

I want to assign responseText to global variable. how can do it

Comment: This might be a useful read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are, basically, the properties of the window object.

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("Get","/topjob/php/data.json");
req.onload = function (){
    window.myNewVariable = req.responseText;
    var ourData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    randerHTML(ourData);
    randerHTML2(ourData);
req.send();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put this:

`globalVariable = req.responseText;`

anywhere in your code where `req.responseText` is defined.

But creating such global variables is definitely **NOT** a good idea. If you need to do so, it means that something's not right with your app's architecture.

Comment: i want to execute for loop when page load. if i added for loop to inside of req.onload = function (){ } its not execute, how can i execute it inside

Answer (score 0):

Declare it just outside the method where this ajax call is written. Making it a global variable is a recipe for introducing unpredictable bugs if the code does not take care of it properly.

```
var topJobData;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("Get","/topjob/php/data.json");
req.onload = function (){
    topJobData = req.responseText;
    var ourData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    randerHTML(ourData);
    randerHTML2(ourData);
    req.send();
};
```